# Как получить ID всех постов wordpress?

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress

Как получить массив хранящий в себе ID всех постов(только постов, не страниц) в Wordpress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$post_IDS = array();

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$post_ID = get_the_ID();
array_push($post_IDS, $post_ID);
endwhile;

echo $post_IDS[3];
```

так вроде бы работает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать запрос к базе, например:

```
 global $wpdb; 
  $sql="SELECT id FROM posts WHERE post_type='post'  ";
  $postsID = $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A);
  print_r($postsID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

Здесь работает класс WP_Query, $args укажите нужные вам

```
$key_count = 0;

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    $posts_ids_array[$key_count] = $post->ID;
    $key_count++ ;

wp_reset_postdata();
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

Получите массив $posts_ids_array с id всех постов из выборки